# Trying to compare 2 text files, getting" IndexError: list index out of range" error

Tags: python, function, text-files, index-error

I have a school assignment: "This program should prompt the user for the names of two text files and compare the contents of the two files to see if they are the same. If they are, the program should simply output “Yes” to the console. If they are not, the script should output “No”, followed by the first lines of each file that differ from each other. The input loop should read and compare lines from each file. The loop should break as soon as a pair of different lines is found. "

The text files are given to us with the comment "The links below contain text for testing. Text1 and Text2 are the same file, Text3 is slightly different. "

I am getting an error when I run the program, saying if f1lines[lineCount] != f2lines[lineCount]:

IndexError: list index out of range

What am I doing wrong?

```
file1 = input("Enter name of first file to compare: ")
file2 = input("Enter name of second file to compare: ")

f1 = open(file1, 'r')
f2 = open(file2, 'r')

f1lines = f1.readlines()
f1.close()
f2lines = f2.readlines()
f2.close()

def compare_lines():
    lineCount = 0

while lineCount != len(f1lines):

    if f1lines[lineCount] == f2lines[lineCount]:
        lineCount += 1
        if lineCount == len(f1lines):
            print("Yes")
    if f1lines[lineCount] != f2lines[lineCount]:
        print("No")
        print(f2lines[lineCount])
```

Comment: `if f1lines[lineCount] != f2lines[lineCount]:` Well, why do you think this should work? In your own words, what values could `lineCount` have? How was the limit determined? In particular, is `f2lines` considered when setting that limit? Do you see why this causes a problem if `f2lines` is shorter than `f1lines`?

Comment: You are very right about that. That was stupid of me, thanks for pointing that out! In my noobish mind, I assumed that would give the output "no" that is needed to compare text files that are not the same but I see how that doesn't work

Comment: It looks like the loop will not exit if the files are different and simply forever print "No" and the line.  You need a `break` at least.

Answer (score 0):

change if to elif

```
elif f1lines[lineCount] != f2lines[lineCount]:
    print("No")
    print(f2lines[lineCount])
    break
```

Comment: By changing this code, this fixes comparing text file 1 and text file 2, thank you very much! Sadly, when I compare text file 1 to text file 3, I am still getting an error



`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\school\python\PythonWorkspace\chapter12Assignment\src\Dif.py", line 31, in <module>
    print(compare_lines())
  File "C:\Users\user\school\python\PythonWorkspace\chapter12Assignment\src\Dif.py", line 23, in compare_lines
    if f1lines[lineCount] == f2lines[lineCount]:
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Use break in elif after print(f2lines[lineCount])

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

No need to write this much code it is much easier with this code. You may try it

```
   file1 = input("Enter name of first file to compare: ")
   file2 = input("Enter name of second file to compare: ")

   f1 = open(file1, 'r')
   f2 = open(file2, 'r')

   f1lines = f1.readlines()
   f1.close()
   f2lines = f2.readlines()
   f2.close()

   if len(f1lines) == len(f2lines):
      print(Yes)
   else:
      print("No)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, my assignment says "If they are not the same, the script should output “No”, followed by the first lines of each file that differ from each other. The input loop should read and compare lines from each file. The loop should break as soon as a pair of different lines is found. "